# Can a push button with a single click using an Arduino have more than one function?

Tags: microcontroller, led

I've tried to google this and failed, but I am trying to figure out if I can use a momentary push button and some controller like an Arduino UNO (which I have) to activate two LED lights, one after the other. My example, say I push the button, the blue LED lights up first for 5 seconds, and right after it shuts off, a red LED lights up for 3 seconds then stops, and all done with a single push.

If I want to do it again, I simply press the button again. Any links or advice would be most appreciated. I am very new to the world of controllers, so I likely am using the wrong wording to do proper searching.

Comment: Just write a program to do whatever you want after the button is pressed.

Comment: Of course! But this isn't really an electronics question - it's a programming question more suited to https://arduino.stackexchange.com.

Comment: :| I see wrong forum, thanks for the redirect!

Comment: The question has a false assumption and is not about doing multiple things from one button. It's really about one button doing one thing, and the one thing it does is to just run a sequence of commands to have two LEDs light up in a sequence.

Comment: Don't forget to put a green check-mark next to the answer that you said was so great in the comments. We work hard for those points! This is how to be a good citizen here on this site. (Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange!)

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD yup and thanks for the reminder, solution below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done easily.

Supposing you connect a normally open button between ground and pin 4 of Arduino, your blue LED with a 330 ohm resistor in series between pin 5 and ground, and your red LED with a 330 ohm resistor in series between pin 6 and ground.

Then the following program should work and match your example (not tested, but it compiles):

```
#define PIN_BUTTON 4
#define PIN_LED_BLUE 5
#define PIN_LED_RED 6

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(PIN_BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(PIN_LED_BLUE, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PIN_LED_RED, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(PIN_LED_BLUE, LOW);
    digitalWrite(PIN_LED_RED, LOW);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

    if(digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON)==0)  //button pressed
    {
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED_BLUE, HIGH);    //turn on blue led
        delay(5000);    //wait for 5000ms = 5s
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED_BLUE, LOW);    //turn off blue led

        digitalWrite(PIN_LED_RED, HIGH);    //turn on red led
        delay(3000);    //wait for 3000ms = 3s
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED_RED, LOW);    //turn off red led
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, Ill give it a shot and report back, thank you for that!